# How to set the xlim and ylim of a FacetGrid

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, facet-grid, lmplot

I'm using `sns.lmplot` to plot a linear regression, dividing my dataset into two groups with a categorical variable.

For both x and y, I'd like to manually set the *lower bound* on both plots, but leave the *upper bound* at the Seaborn default.
Here's a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

n = 200
np.random.seed(2014)
base_x = np.random.rand(n)
base_y = base_x * 2
errors = np.random.uniform(size=n)
y = base_y + errors

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': base_x, 'Y': y, 'Z': ['A','B']*(100)})

mask_for_b = df.Z == 'B'
df.loc[mask_for_b,['X','Y']] = df.loc[mask_for_b,] *2

sns.lmplot('X','Y',df,col='Z',sharex=False,sharey=False)
```

This outputs the following:
[image]

But in this example, I'd like the xlim and the ylim to be (0,*) . I tried using sns.plt.ylim and sns.plt.xlim but those only affect the right-hand plot.
Example:

```
sns.plt.ylim(0,)
sns.plt.xlim(0,)
```

[image]

How can I access the xlim and ylim for each plot in the FacetGrid?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

The `lmplot` function returns a `FacetGrid` instance. This object has a method called `set`, to which you can pass `key=value` pairs and they will be set on each Axes object in the grid.

Secondly, you can set only one side of an Axes limit in matplotlib by passing `None` for the value you want to remain as the default.

Putting these together, we have:

```
g = sns.lmplot('X', 'Y', df, col='Z', sharex=False, sharey=False)
g.set(ylim=(0, None))
```

[image]

### Update

- Positional arguments, `sharex` and `sharey` are deprecate beginning in `seaborn 0.11`

```py
g = sns.lmplot(x='X', y='Y', data=df, col='Z', facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
g.set(ylim=(0, None))
```

Answer (score 97):

You need to get hold of the axes themselves. Probably the cleanest way is to change your last row:

```
lm = sns.lmplot('X','Y',df,col='Z',sharex=False,sharey=False)
```

Then you can get hold of the axes objects (an array of axes):

```
axes = lm.axes
```

After that you can tweak the axes properties

```
axes[0,0].set_ylim(0,)
axes[0,1].set_ylim(0,)
```

creates:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also specify `xlim` and `ylim` parameters of [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) via `facet_kws`:

```py
sns.lmplot(df, x='X', y='Y', col='Z', facet_kws={'xlim': (0, 2), 'ylim': (0, 9)})
```

However, the same limits will be used for all subplots, as they are just [handed over](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/4888797c7aa9e77915474d72bfbbe1dcfe196d45/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L446) to Matplotlib's [`Figure.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots) method. This also means, you can't use `(0, None)`, since it fixes the upper limit to 1. So, this is not really a solution for the OP, but for other cases (e. g. normalized variables like percentages) this can be useful.