# Seaborn PairGrid axes in common ranges

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a PairGrid as shown below. However, I want the x-axes show a common range (1 to 9) and the y-axes show a another common range (0 to 10). How can I do that? Thanks.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white")

df = sns.load_dataset("iris")

g = sns.PairGrid(df, diag_sharey=False, vars=['sepal_length','sepal_width'])
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues_d")
g.map_upper(plt.scatter)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, lw=3)
```

[image]

Comment: `g.set(xlim=(1, 9), ylim=(0, 10))`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25213614/5285918

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you.