# set individual ylim of seaborn lmplot columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I've made a lmplot column plot (subplot) using the following commands:

```
g = sns.lmplot(x=COX, y='dX', data=tidy_data, hue='hue', col='comp', 
col_wrap=8, fit_reg=True, scatter=True, aspect=1.5,
            legend_out=True, truncate=True, scatter_kws={"s": 200})
```

[figure of the plotted lmplot FacetGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxDbB.png)

The FacetGrid seems to set the ylim of all subplots to the maximum value in all of the data. I would like to set the ylim individually for each subplot. I first looked to the answer of this question:

[How to set some xlim and ylim in Seaborn lmplot facetgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212986/how-to-set-some-xlim-and-ylim-in-seaborn-lmplot-facetgrid)

I tested:

```
g.axes.shape
>>> (23, )

g.axes[0]
>>> AxesSubplot(0.0189366,0.704381;0.116079x0.258196)

g.axes[0].set_ylim(0, 1)
>>>
```

However, this method also seems to give the same ylim for all subplots. Maybe I'm not accessing the right axis? I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set some xlim and ylim in Seaborn lmplot facetgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212986/how-to-set-some-xlim-and-ylim-in-seaborn-lmplot-facetgrid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to alter the ylim of one particular plot in the `FacetGrid` you have to explicitly create it with `g = sns.lmplot(..., sharey=False)`

example:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", col="day", hue="day", data=tips, col_wrap=2, size=3, 
               sharey=False)
g.axes[0].set_ylim((0,100))
```

[image]