# using sns.relplot.set to control aesthetics in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

From [How to set some xlim and ylim in Seaborn lmplot facetgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212986/how-to-set-some-xlim-and-ylim-in-seaborn-lmplot-facetgrid) I've find out that you can specify xlim by using

```
g = sns.relplot(data=df_weekday,
            x="date", y="battery/min", kind="scatter", hue="version")
g.set(xlim=('2019-07-16','2019-11-06'))
```

This works perfectly however can I add more parameters inside,

instead of calling plt.xticks(rotation=90) and other controls on each line I want to include all inside g.set().

Furthermore when I try to spread my graph by setting `height=10, aspect=2` however it makes all the fonts too small and having graph without height, aspect makes my graph too squished.

I want to add height, aspect and change all fonts also inside g.set() if possible.

Comment: It's not possible to use `g.set()` for that. For the tick parameters you need to loop over the axes `for ax in g.axes:`. For the size of the plot, you need to specify `height` and `aspect` within the `relplot` call.

Comment: I like height and aspect however aspect messes up my font. I do not want to re-adjust my font with plt.font everytime. Is there another way?

Comment: In fact, neither height, nor aspect change the font. If you have a font of 10 pt set in the rcParams, it will be 10 pt always. It's probably that you perceive the font as being smaller because everything else grows bigger.

Comment: okay so only way to make font grow proportional to graph is just to set font larger in rcParams?