# Seaborn facetgrid add commas to y axis labels

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, visualization

I currently have this graph, created using:

```
fg = sns.catplot(x='metric', y='number', hue='drop', data=df, kind='bar')
```

[image]

I need to change the axis labels to have commas.

I tried:

```
df['number'] = df['number'].apply(lambda x: "{:,}".format(x))
```

However this errors, because neither the x or y values are numeric then (the above changes the data type from numeric to object).

How can I get commas in the y axis values?

I cannot use get_yaxis().set_major_formatter because this is not an attribute of facetgrid.

Comment: FYI, you can get the axes object using `fg.axes` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25213438/5851928)

Answer (score 2):

The for loop in the following code creates the comma format using `StrMethodFormatter`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

#Theme
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

#Example data frame
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Value"]    = [1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 2000000, 5000000] 
df["Category"] = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
fg = sns.catplot(x='Category', y='Value', data=df, kind='bar')

for ax in fg.axes.flat:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))

#So that axis show
plt.tight_layout()

#Show plot
plt.show()
```

[image]