# Set Ranges in Displot (Seaborn)

Tags: seaborn, visualization, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I was trying to plot this using displot.

[This is my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0OKb.png)

my code

```
plt = sns.displot(reg_pred-y_test,kind = 'kde')
```

Now I want to set ranges of X axis (-20,20) and Y axis (0.00 to 0.12).

I tried `plt.xlim(-20,20)`
It gives me the followring error message :

> AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'xlim'

Can anyone help me with setting the ranges?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25212986/7758804

Comment: Please don't assign `plt = ...` as it overwrites `plt` from `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, and causes the error you see.  As `displot` is a figure-level function, returning a `FacetGrid`, the custom name for the return value in seaborn examples is `g = sns.displot(...)`.  Then, you can use `g.set(xlim=(-20, 20))`